# Ocaml list to tree

Tags: list, tree, ocaml, tree-traversal

I want to write a function `load: 'a option list -> 'a tree`, that restores binary tree from the given list, which contains the elements in postfix order.
If the list does not represent any tree, your function should raise the exception
Load (you have to declare it earlier).

The tree is defined as :

```
type ‘a btree = L of ‘a | N of ‘a btree * ‘a btree
```

So far what I did was :

```
exception Load ;;

let rec load l =
    match l with
        | [] -> raise Load
        | Some x::_ -> L x
        | None::t -> N(?,load t)
;;
```

Here's an example of an Input list:

```
[Some 2; Some 0; None; Some 5; Some 9; Some 20; None; None; None]
```

It's kind of tricky how to do it. Since the list is in postfix order, I'm wondering if it will be better to use `List.foldright` function ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should try harder to do your homework (surely there is something interesting to learn), but as you apparently don't care:

```
let load input =
  let rec load stack = function
    | [] -> stack
    | Some elem :: rest -> load (L elem :: stack) rest
    | None :: rest ->
      match stack with
        | right :: left :: stack -> load (N(left, right) :: stack) rest
        | [] | [_] -> failwith "incorrect node arity"
  in
  match load [] input with
    | res :: [] -> res
    | [] -> failwith "no input"
    | _ :: _ :: _ -> failwith "remaining nodes"
```