# OCaml inserting an int list into a binary search tree

Tags: ocaml

If I am given an int list, how do I insert each element from the int list into a given binary search tree one by one in OCaml?

Comment: try the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799582/ocaml-list-to-tree).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let insert_list = List.fold_left insert_element empty_tree
```